# ctrl alt del login not working over VPN

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, vpn

Windows 7 Desktop User connecting to a VPN over wireless.  Connects fine, but after screen locks from no activity the machine will not allow control-alt-delete to let them unlock and login.  Machine goes dark for 2 minutes and then brings back the prompt for control-alt-delete again.

User cannot connect in wired because their machine is too far from Router.  Anyone out there seen and resolved this issue?

Comment: Might need a bit more info.  What VPN and remote desktop client are you using?

Comment: Cisco anyconnect.

Comment: I misspoke.  It is MSVPN talking to Cisco.